# Is there an easy way to have a defined list of items in a database column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "status" column in 2 of my database tables, but the same status types for each one. For instance, an author can have the following status': pending, active, void, suspended. These same status types work for the status of a published article.

Is it proper to just use char() for either table under STATUS and enter either of the 4 listed status', or would it make more database sense to make a "STATUS" table with a STATUS_ID and STATUS_type for each type of status and then just use the STATUS_ID foreign key in either table or future tables?

Simply typing in either of the 4 types would be the easy way, but I'm thinking their may be the possibility of user error...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `enum` field data type to enforce that a value must be once of a pre-selected set of values.  Behind the scenes MySQL actually stores these value as integer representationd to save on storage requirements.

Whether you need a seperate table or not is really up to you.  If you think the set of allowable values need to change dynamically over time, then perhaps it makes good sense (with a foreign key contraint in place to enforce selection of one of the values).  You might also benefit from having the values in a separate table if the values actually represent some sort of real-world objects in your system which need to have their own properties (fields) associated with them.

Comment: I'll look into that idea... right now, i just need a basic "status" field to keep track of authors... appreciated!

Comment: @corradorotondella Then enum is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using an ENUM type for the status column? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be the [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) datatype, a 2nd table will work well too but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

A separate Status lookup table is the way to go. It may actually slow down your queries because you are adding a join, but the normalization benefits outweigh it. The biggest practical benefit is that it makes changing status names MUCH easier.  If you want to change "Pending" to "In Process", you just have to change 1 field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this column in WHERE clause frequently, then it's good idea to make another table for it.

Comment: Why would it be better to have another table if you are using it in where clauses often ?

Comment: Because to compare two integers is faster then to compare two strings.

Answer (score 0):

your proposal for a status table is sound and is a common practice.  Depending on the language your using to program, and enum would be an appropriate alternative, this helps to ensure that only the enum types you define are saved in the database.

PHP:

```
abstract class STATUS
{
    const pending = 1;
    const active = 2;
    const void = 3;
    const suspended = 4;

    function GetConstants()
    {
        $rc = new ReflectionClass($this);
        return $rc->getConstants();
    }
}
```

c#

```
public enum CourseType
{
    pending = 1;
    active = 2;
    void = 3;
    suspended = 4;
}
```